# Mobile can't connect to localhost custom domain with SSL (https://localhost.domain.com)

Tags: wordpress, debugging, xampp, localhost

I set a custom localhost domain (`etc/hosts`) like:

- `127.0.0.1 localhost.domain.com`

Where I run a Wordpress installation with XAMPP, I'm on Windows 10, I have self signed SSL to https://localhost.domain.com.

The problem is that I cannot connect with my mobile phone to localhost (192.x.x.x) and perform some debug operations.

Of course I can access the website from my desktop machine without a problem.

Comment: How a localhost site can run on mobile device? Are you drunk or what?

Comment: Lol @Ali... If you read well, I'm running the website on XAMPP, Windows 10. ;-)

Comment: Ok then there may be permalink problem or domain issue. Check in wordpress permalink settings.

Comment: Not that, but thank you.